# How to change the initial view in Xcode in XCode 6.2

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode6

- Create a new project with a single view.
- Select Main.storyboard delete view controller.
- Add new tableViewController.
- Set InitialViewController option is not there in Attributes Inspector.
- How can I set it?

Comment: and in the navigationController of tableviewcontroller?

Comment: I just followed your steps and it's working. The option appears in Attributes inspector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the available objects you will see the Storyboard Entry point.

[image]

Drag and drop this onto your view controller to make it the initial scene.

Answer (score 1):

Select TableViewController in left sidebar

[image: try it]

Comment: Pranesh231286 , for xcode 6.2 u may select «storyboard entry point» in object library. UPD: I slowpoke :(